# Why does registerForRemoteNotificationTypes sometimes fail?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm writing an IOS app with Push Notifications.

I call `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes`.

When I run it on my iPhone 4S IOS 5.1, i get `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`.

However

When I run it on my iPad 1 IOS 5.1.1 or my iPad 2 IOS 6.1.3 I get `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError`.

The message is "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application".

What can I do to make it succeed on the iPads too?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Provisioning Profile & select the Provisioning Profile in Xcode will clear the error!

Comment: No but something is missing which is hard to figure out then simply creating the new one with carefully following the steps, most time it help!

Comment: @RogerWernersson Provisioning Profile is per device if you are in development (vs production). You can go log into developer website with your developer account to add device (your iPad), then add the new devices to the provisioning profile associated with your app with push notification.

Comment: Should I ever create more than one Certificate Signing Request? I've been creating a new one for ever certificate I've requested.

Comment: hmm i think one for development and for distribution